# Javascript : date automatically increments by +1 value (Convert String to Date object)

Tags: javascript, string, validation, date

I use `Date()` function to convert string to date object . The problem is , If i give `Date("April , 31 ,2012")`  it will take it as `May , 01 , 2012` (for the rest of the days its working) Please check my approach is correct from the code below.

```
function TestDate(objValue,strError){

    var ret=true;
    var frmdate=objValue.value;
    var datesplit=frmdate.split("-");
    var y =datesplit[0];
    var m=datesplit[1];
    var d=datesplit[2];
    var testdate;
    // Create date object using given input data
    testdate = new Date(m+"/"+d+"/"+y);
    alert("Created date"+testdate.toString());
    var td=testdate.getDate();
    var tm=testdate.getMonth()+1;
    var ty =testdate.getFullYear();
    alert(d+"="+td);
    alert(m+"="+tm);
    alert(y+"="+ty);
    var valid=((d==td) && (m==tm) && (y==ty));
    alert(valid);
    if(valid == false)
    {
        ret =false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: April only have 30 days, by default it will add a day to 31-04, therefore, 1st of May will return.

Comment: objValue.value has "2012-04-25" format

Answer (score 1):

As sayed by @ajreal in comments, April has only 30 days.

The internal date object increments the month to have a valid date.

Comment: @ajreal  Thank you for your response. I already know april 31 is not valid date thats why it take may 01, But in my module i want date object for april 31 so that i can compare my form date to date object for validate my formdate. Now i realize that if i create date object for april 31 , i cant validate my form date.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
testdate = new Date(m+"/"+d+"/"+y);
```

is depends on non-standard, implementation specific parsing of the string. Far better to use the data you started with to create a date unambiguously:

```
testdate = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
```

As for validating a date, a simple function using an ISO8601 compliant date of format yyyy-mm-dd is:

```
function validateDate(dateString) {
  var bits = dateString.split('-');
  var date = new Date(bits[0], bits[1] - 1, bits[2]);
  return date && date.getFullYear() == bits[0] && date.getDate() == bits[2];
}
```

That way if the string passed to the function is turned into a date, you can check that the date so created matches the input. If not, it wasn't valid and the function returns false. It also returns false if the string doesn't get turned into a date.